# How to make a JPanel scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JFrame and In which I want to show a JInternal Frame whihc contains a Jpanel. This JPanel contains some JLabels and JTextFields. As the size of the JInternal Frame is smaller than the size of the JPanel. The JInternal Frame is not resizable so I want to make the jpanel which contains the form should be scrollable. Here is the demo code of it in this code I have not used the JInternal Frame for making it simple. But when I execute this code its not showing scrollbar. 
   Please tell me friends whats wrong with this code. I want to use setBounds() method instead of setDimension() method or setPreferredSize() method. So is it possible?

Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class InterfaceDesign {

public static void main(String args[]){
    InterfaceDesign id=new InterfaceDesign();
    id.getPnlProjectDetail("My Project");
}

public void getPnlProjectDetail(String strProjectName){
    JPanel pnlProjectDetail=new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrProjectDetail;
    pnlProjectDetail.setLayout(null);
    pnlProjectDetail.setBounds(0, 0, 400,400);
    JFrame frmtest=new JFrame();
    frmtest.setBounds(1,1,300,200);

    JLabel lblFirstName=new JLabel("First Name");
    JLabel lblLastName=new JLabel("Last Name");
    JLabel lblAddress=new JLabel("Address");
    JLabel lblCity=new JLabel("City");
    JLabel lblZipCode=new JLabel("Zip Code");
    JLabel lblPhone=new JLabel("Phone");
    JLabel lblEmailID=new JLabel("Emain Id");

    JTextField tfFirstName=new JTextField();
    JTextField tfLastName=new JTextField();
    JTextField tfAddress=new JTextField();
    JTextField tfCity=new JTextField();
    JTextField tfZipCode=new JTextField();
    JTextField tfPhone=new JTextField();
    JTextField tfEmailID=new JTextField();

    lblFirstName.setBounds(25, 55, 85, 20);
    tfFirstName.setBounds(25, 85, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblFirstName);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfFirstName);

    lblLastName.setBounds(25, 115, 85, 20);
    tfLastName.setBounds(25, 145, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblLastName);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfLastName);

    lblAddress.setBounds(25, 175, 85, 20);
    tfAddress.setBounds(25, 205, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblAddress);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfAddress);

    lblCity.setBounds(25, 235, 85, 20);
    tfCity.setBounds(25, 265, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblCity);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfCity);

    lblZipCode.setBounds(25, 295, 85, 20);
    tfZipCode.setBounds(25, 325, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblZipCode);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfZipCode);

    lblPhone.setBounds(25, 355, 85, 20);
    tfPhone.setBounds(25, 385, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblPhone);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfPhone);

    lblEmailID.setBounds(25, 415, 85, 20);
    tfEmailID.setBounds(25, 445, 85, 20);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(lblEmailID);
    pnlProjectDetail.add(tfEmailID);

    scrProjectDetail=new JScrollPane(pnlProjectDetail);
    frmtest.setContentPane(scrProjectDetail);
    //frmtest.add(scrProjectDetail);
    frmtest.setVisible(true);
    frmtest.setResizable(false);
    frmtest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //return pnlProjectDetail;      
}


}
```

Please guide me friends!
Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call setPreferredSize() of the panel in the JScrollPane.

But it's much much better to use LayoutManager!

Comment: Thank You! Friend! Your solution works  but can you please explain me why its not worked with setBounds() method? And another thing is that I was expecting that as I press Tab button on keyboard i.e. as focus moves from textfield to another scroll bar will move automatically but its not happening? so Please give any hint on it?